# СчАстливо или счастлИво?

Tags: фонетика

Когда мы с кем-то прощаемся, то говорим ему: "СчастлИво" или более развернуто - "Счастливо оставаться", и ударение тут ставится на И. Но при этом в обороте, например, "они жили долго и счАстливо" мы ставим ударение на А.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно говорить: "счастлИво" или "счАстливо"? Или оба ударения правильные, но от них зависит смысл слова?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По словарю Резниченко:

СчАстливо и счастлИво - допускаются оба варианта.

СчастлИво оставаться! - один вариант.

ПРИМЕРЫ

"Я запомнил, как диво, Тот лесной хуторок, Задремавший счастлИво Меж звериных дорог" (Н. Рубцов).

И много лет прошло, и счАстливо Я прожил без тебя, а все ж Порой я думаю опасливо:
Жива ли ты и где живешь (В. Набоков).
…